# SQL query NOT EXIST very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize an SQL query as it is slow, and gets slower when the query result is high.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM comments  
 WHERE 
     DATE(created_on) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
     AND comments.group_id = " . $group_id . " 
     AND comments.user_id != " . $user_id . "  
     AND NOT EXISTS ( 
         SELECT *
         FROM reads
         WHERE 
             comments.post_id = reads.notification_id 
             AND comments.group_id = reads.group_id  
             AND reads.user_id = " . $user_id . " 
             AND comments.nature1 = reads.notification_type
             AND comments.created_on < reads.read_date
     )  
LIMIT 8
```

There are indexes concerned fields and Tables are quite big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter, this condition:

```
DATE(created_on) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Should be rewritten as:

```
created_on >= current_date
```

This is functionally equivalent, and not using date functions on the column being filtered gives the database a chance to use an index.

Then, consider the following indexes:

```
comments(group_id, created_on, user_id)
reads(notification_id, group_id, user_id, notification_type, created_on)
```

These are two multi-column indexes (called compound indexes), not individual indexes on each column. You'll notice that they match the `where` predicates of the query and subquery. The ordering of columns in the index is important (especially in the index on `comments`): you want columns that have equality predicates first, then columns with inequality predicates.

Finally: do you really need `select *`? It is better to reduce the list to the columns you actually need; if there is just a few of them, you might want to try and add them to the index on `comments`.

Side notes:

- `limit` without `order by` is usually not useful. This gives you an arbitrary set of rows out of those that match - and the results may not be consistent over consecutive executions of the same query over the same dataset
- consider using prepared statements rather than concatenating variables in the query string; this allows MySQL to recognize the query, and reuse an already prepared execution plan (that's a tiny gain, but always good to take) - and, more important, it prevents SQL injection.

Comment: Wow man ! just the created_on >= current_date made a huge difference ! Thank you for the extended recommendations !

Answer (score 0):

For your query, you want indexes on:

- `comments(group_id, created_on, user_id)`
- `reads(post_id, group_id, notification_type, user_id, created_on)`.

Are these the two of the indexes that you have?

Comment: Hi @Gordon, Yes, indexes for the sited columns exist

Comment: @ABMoslih . . . Not indexes.  Those two particular indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the answers mentioned here, here's a general advice.

An `EXPLAIN` in front of a `SELECT`query shows you how the query will be executed.

i.e. `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM T1`

Now, the column **key_len** shows you the size in bytes for one index item. The lower this value is the more index items fit into the same memory size an they can be faster processed. 
**Rows** shows you the expected number of rows the query needs to scan, the lower the better.

Answer (score 0):

- Minor potential improvement, replace the clause `AND comments.group_id = reads.group_id` with `AND reads.group_id = " . $group_id . "`

  This makes no difference because `comments.group_id` is already always equal to `$group_id` and the constant may be easier for the database to match. However, the database may already be making this optimisation internally, or otherwise running the query in a way where it can't take advantage of this.
- Major concern: do not construct queries using the `.` operator; instead, use the relevant function in your library or framework to separately pass the SQL query (with placeholders) and the values (`group_id` and `user_id`). Constructing queries using the `.` operator is incredibly dangerous.